# scraping data from websites with scrapy and output to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, scrapy, chatbot

I want to build a simple chatbot (with nodejs) that scrapes data from websites to users by using scrapy (python framework). My problem is how does my nodejs app gets the scraped data from the scrapy framework.

Answer (score 0):

Use a node equivalent of [scrapy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scrapy) or another node module like the built in [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) (recommended).